# Is a model that satisfies a predicate language with identity a model of Peano Arithmetic?

Tags: logic

Exercise:

> Let M be a model which satisfies all the theorems of a predicate
>   language with identity.
>   Is M a model of Peano Arithmetic (PA)?

Solution given by the lecture notes I'm reading: yes, because of theorem 1.

In the lecture notes Theorem 1 goes as follows:

> If M is an interpretation of the language of a theory T which makes
>   true all the proper axioms of T, than M is a model of T.

Also, a theory is defined as

> a set of sentences closed under derivation (i.e., as a set of
>   theorems).

I don't understand why the right answer is yes. I thought that as PA contains more axioms than a simple predicate language with identity a model that satisfies the latter wouldn't automatically satisfy PA.

Comment: "Let $M$ be a model" _of what_? Without context this does indeed sound very strange. Are you sure there isn't something relevant in the lines immediately above that exercise? Do you have the exercise from somewhere you can link to, or a book you can give us a citation to?

Comment: **IF**, as per Th.1, the model $M$ satisfy also the proper axioms of PA, it is a model of PA.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm slightly curious what the _definition_ of "model" is here -- I can't imagine any sensible definition of that word that's _not_ exactly what the quoted "Theorem 1" is saying.

Comment: I suppose "model" in the first use is meant to mean simply "structure" without respect to a particular theory. At least, "model" is often loosely used in this broader sense.